# How to undo forceav commands?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

A few weeks ago I found out about console commands. So I started playing around with them. I changed speed, size, things like that just to mess around. They usually didn't last through saves. Then I played around with my level, just to see what it would be like to be "all powerful" using a forceav command. I changed carry weight, too. A few days ago I decided I wanted to go back to my original, non-cheated game, but the levels and carry weight are stuck. Now when I try to fix it, nothing happens. Does anyone know how to undo forceav commands?

Comment: "**Warning**: Use console commands with caution! It is easily possible to mess up your game if you modify settings at the console. […] Create a permanent saved game before experimenting with the console." ([Skyrim Console, UESP Wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console))

Comment: Your save game might be unfixable. The console itself can have bugs, and some of its behaviours are irregular. I don't believe you can decrease level, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `player.setlevel x` to modify your character's level with the console. To fix your carry weight, use `player.getavinfo carryweight` and check the auto-calculated value, then use `player.forceav carryweight x` where x is your auto-calculated carry weight. You can use `player.removeperk perkID` to remove perks, use `help %perk name%` to find the perk's ID.

In the future I recommend using `modav` to cheat, as these are easier to revert - just re-run the command with the value multiplied by -1.

Comment: The carry weight commands worked. As for the levels, there is a command called "player.removeperk (perk #) so now I'm playing as if the extra stuff never happened. Thank you for the commands to fix carry weight. That was the biggest difference I couldn't fix (until your answer).

Comment: actually, this is not correct. player.setlevel X will change your character level to X.

Comment: @tehdoommarine have you tested this? The wiki disagrees with you http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console

Comment: @kotekzot - yes. when i was playing, i often set my level to 40 (or higher) and entered a cave so the enemies would be tougher. i then used it to get back to normal level. look here: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29

Comment: one more thing. if you were level 66 and say 3/4ths to level 67 and you do this, you will be level 1 but the 3/4ths of a level will still exist. this will cause Level Up to appear, but only to level 9. If you do this with your level bar empty, you won't get the level up at all. this can be fixed by advancing a skill just until you level up and get a blank bar then doing the setlevel command